# How to select only distinct fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table of customer addresses:

```
CName           |   AddressLine
-------------------------------
John Smith      | 123 Nowheresville
Jane Doe        | 456 Evergreen Terrace
John Smith      | 999 Somewhereelse
Joe Bloggs      | 1 Second Ave
```

I want to pick CName with distinct AddressLine means i dont want to pick "John Smith " as it has two addresses. How do i do that?

Comment: Do you mean "unique" instead of "distinct"? Meaning you want all `CName`s that have only one address line?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT CName
FROM Addresses
GROUP BY CName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT AddressLine) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the distinct rows by doing:

```
select cname, min(AddressLine) as AddressLine
from t
group by cname
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`:

```
Select  CName, AddressLine
From    YourTable   A
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    YourTable   B
    Where   A.CName = B.CName
    And     A.AddressLine <> B.AddressLine
)
```

Edit to address performance:

```
Create Table Test (CName Varchar (20), AddressLine Varchar (50));

Insert Test Values 
('John Smith', '123 Nowheresville'),
('Jane Doe', '456 Evergreen Terrace'),
('John Smith', '999 Somewhereelse'),
('Joe Bloggs', '1 Second Ave')


select cname, min(AddressLine) as AddressLine
from test
group by cname
having count(*) = 1;

Select  CName, AddressLine
From    Test   A
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    Test   B
    Where   A.CName = B.CName
    And     A.AddressLine <> B.AddressLine
);
```

Execution plans:

[image]

Comment: The trade-off with this approach is it requires a [correlate subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).  But it would work.

Comment: @destination-data While it does use a correlated subquery to determine the existence of the records, the execution plans generated are actually more efficient than the `GROUP BY HAVING` alternative. (See edit.)

Comment: Nice!  Hard to argue with an execution plan.  I felt bad adding that comment, it wasn't meant as a criticism.  I just wanted to highlight the concept to the OP, and anyone else who comes here looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.CName
FROM Addresses a
GROUP BY a.CName
HAVING COUNT(a.AddressLine) = 1
```